# How to Install Ubuntu server inside Windows

Tags: installation, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

**Installation**
How do I Install Ubuntu server inside Windows?  I want to install Ubuntu server inside my windows desktop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run Ubuntu inside Windows 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583/how-can-i-run-ubuntu-inside-windows-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to be specifically Ubuntu server, and you want to run it in Windows, the best way would be to run it inside a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).

That way, Windows stays running and Ubuntu will run in a box inside Windows as if it's another Windows program.

My choice of virtual machine software (particularly on Windows) is [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

[Here is a step by step guide if you want it.](http://adigitalnotepad.com/post/howto-setup-ubuntu-server-on-virtualbox)  Hopefully it's not too out of date.

Note that you'll probably need/want the i386 version of Ubuntu server - and you install it from the ISO (you don't have to burn the ISO to a CD).  And you'll probably want to give it at least 300MB of RAM.

Also if you want a network connection to your Ubuntu server from Windows, you may run into the issue [I describe here](https://askubuntu.com/a/143972/54256) unless you set up "bridged" networking mode in Virtualbox.

Comment: Maybe I crashed their server - that step by step guide seems to have gone offline now.  Here's [Google's cached copy](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://adigitalnotepad.com/post/howto-setup-ubuntu-server-on-virtualbox&hl=en&prmd=imvns&strip=1)

Comment: it is possible to create duel boot?

Comment: Yes, but that would be a separate question.  It also wouldn't be possible to use Windows while your server is running that way.